# Given a few facts in prolog. I can't seem to create a rule which returns the variables don't have a relationship with given variable

Tags: prolog

The facts are listed below. I can't seem to create the proper rule called notneighbors which returns all the letters that are not neighbor to the given letter. Or don't have a neighborletters(X,Y) relationship with given letter.

```
neighborletters(a,b,beggining_letters).
neighborletters(b,a,beggining_letters).
neighborletters(j,k,middle_letters).
neighborletters(k,j,middle_letters).
neighborletters(x,y,last_letters).
neighborletters(y,x,last_letters).
```

So far I have come up with the below rule and many other variations of it.

```
notneighbor(X,Y):-    
    neighborletters(A,B, _),
    neighborletters(B,A, _),
    X \= A,
    Y \= B.
```

but whenever I do a query with the above rule.

```
?- notneighbor(a, X).
```

I get a boolean false instead of the desired returns

```
j 
k  
x  
y
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your query, `notneighbor(a, X)`, the second argument is not instantiated. Therefore, the last goal in your rule, `Y \= B`, is false as a variable can always be unified with any term. Try instead:

```
neighbor_letters(a, b, beggining_letters).
neighbor_letters(b, a, beggining_letters).
neighbor_letters(j, k, middle_letters).
neighbor_letters(k, j, middle_letters).
neighbor_letters(x, y, last_letters).
neighbor_letters(y, x, last_letters).

not_neighbor(X, Y):-    
    neighbor_letters(X, _, _),
    neighbor_letters(Y, _, _),
    X \== Y,
    \+ neighbor_letters(Y, X, _),
    \+ neighbor_letters(X, Y, _).
```

This will give you:

```
| ?- not_neighbor(a, X).

X = j ? ;
X = k ? ;
X = x ? ;
X = y
yes
```

This definition for the `not_neighbor/2` predicate can also return pairs of letters that are not neighbors:

```
| ?- not_neighbor(X, Y).

X = a
Y = j ? ;
X = a
Y = k ? ;
X = a
Y = x ? ;
X = a
Y = y ? ;
...
```

Still an issue with it, however, it returns duplicated answers. E.g.

```
| ?- not_neighbor(b, y).

yes
| ?- not_neighbor(y, b).

yes
```

Is that a problem? If yes, can you solve it continuing from here?

Comment: thank you for the answer Paulo, but is there a way I can get rid of the duplicates?

Comment: It seems that non-neighbor letters always belong to separate sets (where the sets are `beggining_letters `, `middle_letters `, and `last_letters`). Taking advantage of this information, you can try to generate solutions in a different way that would avoid duplicates.